# I would like to change from the vertical input to column input using streamlit also, columns have to be dynamic

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

```
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

st.header('Input Data')
p = np.array([[4,3,6,2],[1,4,3,5],[2,5,2,3],[5,2,4,1],[3,6,1,4]])
st.dataframe(p)
t = []
tb = len(p)
st.subheader('Enter the T value into row for multiplication')
for i in range(tb):
  value = st.number_input(f'row{i}:', min_value=0, max_value=10, step=1)
  t.append(value)
t = np.array(t)
t = np.tile(t, (p.shape[1], 1)).T 
p_mod = np.multiply(p, t)

st.header('Output Data')
st.dataframe(p_mod)
```

Suppose If I run the above code I would get the number input in vertical order but I would like to have in horizontal order

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [st.columns](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns)!

Maybe try

```py
c = st.columns(tb)
for i in range(tb):
  value = c[i].number_input(f'row{i}:', min_value=0, max_value=10, step=1)
  t.append(value)
```